# Do I need to wait() in the parent process after a fork?

Tags: c, linux, unix, fork, wait

I'm wondering if I have to wait() for all child process to finish in the parent program?

I have read the manuals and some online resources about fork(), but none of them mentioned that a wait() in the parent is enforced.

However, if I do not wait in the parent program, the process does not terminate but just does nothing until I press enter, and than terminates.

Comment: It looks like you are confusing threads with processes...

Comment: Nah I don't think so, just some sloppy writing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the parent process doesn't use a system call of the `wait()`-family for its children processes, it could simply die first.

When a parent process dies, all of its children processes are moved under process `init` with PID == 1 in the process tree. So the process `init` is their new parent process.

---

I **guess** the reason you observe this behaviour with `<Enter>` (just a guess, it could be wrong) is because the parent process is terminated earlier than its children, so your terminal's prompt is printed before some of the children's output. When you press `<Enter>`, the prompt is printed again. Check again the output carefully.

Comment: Thanks man, it totally was what you said about the terminal's prompt being printed somewhere halfway through the output and I just missed it.