# Using fork() in simplest form need to hit enter to finish execution

Tags: c, fork, pid

I want to run some simple example to find out how `fork()` system call work.

Its work but need to hit enter to exit the program after printing `child process`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h> 

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0){
        printf("child process\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("parent process\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

## compile, run & output

```
ss@ss:~$ gcc dd.c -o dd
ss@ss:~$ ./dd
parent process
ss@ss:~$ child process
```

after print child process on screen program need to hit enter key to 
return to the terminal.

[image: terminal wait for enter new command]

Terminal wait for enter new command, if just hit enter return, write 
`ss@ss:` and OK.

Or we can enter any other terminal command
and it executes.

I want to know why this behavior occur and if really program finished after printing `child process` why terminal not show `ss@ss:~$`

Here is my machine information

***gcc --version***

```
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
```

***uname -a***

```
Linux ss 4.8.0-36-generic #36~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sun Feb 5 09:39:41 UTC 2017 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

***EDIT***

Besides **Felix Guo** answer by adding `wait(NULL)` after `printf("Parent process")`, forced parent to wait for child process.

I find another way for it [from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45916354/fork-in-background-dont-work-correct) by redirecting output of program to an arbitrary file with `>` operator in terminal.

In execute command:

```
./dd > out.txt
```

it redirects outputs to out.txt file. 
if we cat this file:

```
$cat out.txt
parent process
child process
```

this is another way to see correct output of a program with `fork()`.

***[Edit 2]***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0){
        printf("child process: \n\t");
        printf("PID: %d\n\tPPID: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
    }
    else{
        printf("parent process: \n\t");
        printf("PID: %d\n\tPPID: %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
        wait(NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

***Output***

```
parent process: 
    PID: 4344
    PPID: 4336    < --- OS
child process: 
    PID: 4345
    PPID: 4344    < --- parent process
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54849218/output-from-fork-in-c?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23714398/do-i-need-to-wait-in-the-parent-process-after-a-fork?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your parent process exits before waiting for your child process to complete, so the parent process will complete, which is what the terminal is waiting for, so the terminal will return to it's command input state, thus outputting `ss@ss...`. Then your child processes prints and flushes `stdout` to the screen, which then outputs `child process` to the terminal, but since the terminal already outputted the prompt `ss@ss`, it ends up after the prompt.

The way to solve this is to wait for the child process to exit before `return 0` in the parent process. You can use `wait(NULL)` after `printf("Parent process")` to wait for child process as described here: [Make parent wait for all child processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461744/make-parent-wait-for-all-child-processes)

Comment: OK its true, thanks in advance to you and dbush. using `wait(NULL)` need  ` #include <sys/wait.h>`, but i am not accept it to see others opinion.

Answer (score 2):

It may not look like it, but the terminal is ready to accept new commands right after the parent process finishes.

What is happening is that the shell is printing the prompt, then the child process (which is running concurrently with the shell) outputs a string.  If you were to enter another command without pressing the enter key first to see another prompt, you will see that the command will run.

For example:

```
[dbush@dbush ~]$ ./x1
parent process
[dbush@dbush ~]$ child process
echo hello
hello
[dbush@dbush ~]$
```

Here, I type `echo hello` while the cursor is at the far left and the command is run.