# fork in background don't work correct

Tags: c, linux

I run this prog. in foreground and background:

```
int main()    
{
    int pid;
    printf("App Start pid=%d!\n",getpid());

    while(1) {
        pid=fork();
        if(pid==0) {
            printf("Child\n\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        else if(pid>0) {
            printf("Parent\n");
        }    
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

in foreground:

```
$ ./fork
```

result is:

```
App Start pid=1360!    
Parent    
Child    
Parent    
Child    
...
```

in background:

```
$./fork > out.txt &
$cat out.txt    
App Start pid=1368!    
Child    
App Start pid=1368!    
Parent    
Child    
App Start pid=1368!    
Parent    
Parent    
Child    
...
```

Why does the app 'restart' in background?
I don't understand what happening. 
How can i make fork to work correctly in background app?
Thanks

Comment: Another good answer on buffering of stdout : stackoverflow.com/a/39536803/646887

Answer (score 4):

This has to do with the *output buffers*: newly created process are writing over and over what their parent already `print`ed.  Notice that the message does not change, i.e.: it is always `App Start pid=1368!`.

Place `fflush(stdout)` after the first call to `printf()`:

```
printf("App Start pid=%d!\n",getpid());
fflush(stdout);
```

This way the output buffer will be *flushed* before creating the children processes.

---

Note that by starting the `fork` program without redirecting `stdout` (i.e.: `$ ./fork`), `stdout` is *line-buffered* by default. For that reason, a flush of `stdout` is already performed every time it receives a *new-line character*.

Comment: Interesting. Note The amount of times "parent" is printed increases.

Comment: Correct answer, might want to add why it works without redirection ... (`stdout` line-buffered by default)